# Selecting for a specific character

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, select-by-attribute

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 and editing a file GDB and a string field.

I have several fields that are similar to the following, 34-01, 23-14, 87-09, 23-12...

I am trying to select for fields that have a "0" as the fourth character.

Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: maybe try an index? like:   field[3] == '0'

Answer (score 5):

Use this query:

```
"FIELDNAME" LIKE '___0%'
```

The three underscores (`_`) each serve as a single-character wildcard, meaning the `0` is in the 4th position. The `%` serves as a wildcard of indeterminate length, allowing anything (or nothing) to come after the `0`.